# All not-invertible matrices like $A$ in which $A^2=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix like $A \in M_{n}(F)$ is invertible iff there exists a matrix like $B$ such that $AB=BA=I_n$.

Now the question  :
There are matrices like $X$ in which $X^2=X$ but $X$ is not invertible.  Can we specify those matrices?  I mean, do all of them have a common property?

Comment: There is only one invertible matrix $X$ such that $X^2=X$: the identity matrix.  This is intuitive once you understand these matrices as projection operators.

Comment: @Paul I'm not asking about the invertible matrices. i'm afraid i don't get your point ...

Comment: Then you need to clarify what you mean by "specify."  I specified their actions: they project all vectors into a subspace.  What kind of specification are you looking for?

Comment: @Paul For example, all the matrices in which the first column is $1$ and other elements are zero.

Comment: It depends on your basis.  I will describe in an answer below.

Comment: @ctst Thanks :)

Comment: Did you have a look at [Idempotent matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix $X$ such that $X^2=X$ is a projection operator.  The specification of the matrix depends on the basis, but the simplest way to write it when you have a normed vector space is in terms of an orthogonal basis of the projection subspace and the space perpendicular to the projection subspace.  In this basis, the matrix is diagonal, with 1's on the diagonal for the basis vectors of the projection subspace, and zeroes otherwise.  A similarity transform will give you an arbitrary form.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the notion of "orthogonal" makes sense in this setting - the field $ F $ could be a finite field, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit to specify.

Comment: You have a small mistake here. Just when $X$ is an orthogonal projection you will have this nice diagonal matrix when you do it like that. Consider $X=\{\{1,1\},\{0,0\}\}$ for example. But you can choose a space perpendicular relativ to $X$ (meaning the eigenspace/mainspace-complement of the image) and you will get that nice diagonalform. Best answer would be a merge of the two given answers.

Comment: @ctst I don't understand your example.  Is it a diagonal matrix?  But then it fits what I described.

Comment: No it doesn't fit what you described. The perpendicular space to the projection space is the $y$-axis and the projection space is the $x$-axis. So we already chose the correct basis, but obviously $X$ is not diagonal. $X$ is the matrix with $1$s in the first row and $0$s in the second row.

Answer (score 3):

Any matrix satisfying $ X^2 = X $ is diagonalizable since its minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors, and its eigenvalues are either $ 0 $ or $ 1 $. Therefore, up to a change of basis, any such matrix $ X $ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries in the set $ \{ 0, 1 \} $. This implies that the only such invertible matrix is the identity matrix (which also follows by multiplying both sides by $ X^{-1} $).

Comment: Just to extend your point: The minimalpolynom divides $X^2-X=(X-1)X$ (since if you plugin your matrix you will get $0$). We already figured out $X\neq I$ and if $X\neq0$ holds we have this is the minimalpolynom.